# Git: Is it possible to make an alias for pull?

Tags: git, github

I want to update some external repository every time I use `git pull`. Because the external repository is not using git I made a python script to update it. To make it more easy I created a git alias like this:

```
update = !git pull && python update_external_repo.py
```

This works well, but it's a new "command" for git (`update`) and I don't want it. Is it possible to execute same thing as for `git update`, but for `git pull` instead? If not, is it possible to make a hook for `git pull`?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot make `git pull` behave differently.  Git purposefully does not support aliases that match the same name as a command.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use git for the external repo?

Comment: Yes, it is developed/maintained by other team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use something like the git hook for post-merge?

`post-merge`
       *This hook is invoked by git merge, which happens when a git pull is
       done on a local repository. The hook takes a single parameter, a status
       flag specifying whether or not the merge being done was a squash merge.
       This hook cannot affect the outcome of git merge and is not executed,
       if the merge failed due to conflicts.
       This hook can be used in conjunction with a corresponding pre-commit
       hook to save and restore any form of metadata associated with the
       working tree (eg: permissions/ownership, ACLS, etc). See
       contrib/hooks/setgitperms.perl for an example of how to do this.*

Comment: The main problem with merge hooks is that they are not executed for empty pulls. This is not my desired behaviour as I want to update external repo even when git repo was not updated.